# don't create notification when app is running

Tags: android

When i recevie notification from GCM , how can i know app is running?
because if my app is running i don't want to create notification.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) { // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that
         * GCM will be extended in the future with new message types, just
         * ignore any message types you're not interested in, or that you
         * don't recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // if app not running 
            sendNotification();
            // if app is running 
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(
                    Constants.BroadcastAction.DISPLAY_REQUEST);
            sendBroadcast(intent2);

        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: in Activity in onPause/onResume add code which will change some global boolean state which will indicate if Activity is running .... in onHandleIntent check this state ...

Comment: set that check in every activity ?

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936877/show-push-notification-only-when-app-is-not-running-android will help you