# Show push notification only when app is not running android

Tags: android, push-notification

In my application I have push notification integrated with `GCM`. Its working fine whenever notification comes its appearing. But push notification come even when user is inside the app. I want notifications to appear only when user is outside the app.

Here is my code for push notification:

> GcmBroadcastReceiver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getPackage().getName(), 
            GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

> GCMnotificationIntentService.Class

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

public static int notificationId = 10;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
private boolean login_status = false;


public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

public static final String TAG = GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if ( !extras.isEmpty() ) { // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that
         * GCM will be extended in the future with new message types, just
         * ignore any message types you're not interested in, or that you
         * don't recognize.
         */
        if ( GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType) ) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if ( GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType) ) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if ( GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType) ) {
            sendNotification(extras.getString("message"));
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg)).setContentText(msg);
    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    mBuilder.setSound(uri);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId++, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

> In ManifestFile

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.medlife.deliveryagent" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you added permission  for <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission
        android:name="....permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name=".....permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
?

Comment: You have control what to show, or show not to show in notifications. Just you have to find app is in foreground I think. This link of SO discusses about that. Just check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504632/how-can-i-tell-if-android-app-is-running-in-the-foreground

Comment: @Amit I have added all the permission in manifest file. then only its working

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544165/starting-app-only-if-its-not-currently-running/30703555#30703555

Comment: You mean if you have exited your app then you want to show notification??

Comment: @Clairvoyant : Yes exactly .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do something like this to check whether you app is in foreground or not by calling below method and depending on returning value true or false do your rest of work

```
public boolean checkApp(){
       ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this
                .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // get the info from the currently running task
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("YourPackage")) {
            return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
  }
```

Comment: For packageName can i give particular classname ,

Comment: Yeah you can use class name also format would be: `pacakgename + classname`

Comment: I have one more doubt. i have home screen with navigation drawer . suppose i am in second fragement i am getting notification. if i tap that notificaition it should redirect to The FirstFragement . how to do that any idea??

Comment: As of API v21 `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks` is deprecated, so this solution should not be used anymore.

Comment: This is depcreated.

Answer (score 2):

> Kotlin

```
 fun isAppRunning(context: Context, packageName: String): Boolean {
    val activityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    val procInfos = activityManager.runningAppProcesses
    if (procInfos != null) {
        for (processInfo in procInfos) {
            if (processInfo.processName == packageName) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Really nice solution, it works perfectly and it's better than the accepted answer, because the as of API v21 ActivityManager.getRunningTasks is deprecated, as mentioned by @wvdz.